# How to handle deployment of Spotfire reports between environments?

Tags: spotfire

How to handle deployment of Spotfire reports between environments ?

I know of a way for doing that by just having separate folders for DEV, UAT and PROD and for either re-applying of all the changes on each of envs or by rewiring db connection.

I wonder if there is some better idea among you guys..

Comment: Can you elaborate? You want to manage deploying one dxp to multiple environments, or...? Is UAT user acceptance training or...? Is envs environments?

Comment: UAT - user acceptance tests - but it can also be just TEST - I ve given examples of 3 environments between which the DXP files deployment is necessary. It is not only to manage DXPs but also Information links and all the other files related to creation of DXP files so basically everything. Envs is my acronym for environments.

Comment: I think i understand now. If you change an IL in one dxp you want it to change in all of them, etc, versus having to reopen each dxp and save it with the new association.

Comment: I expect that you have multiple environments. And first you create sth in DEV, and then you wish the thing tested so you need to promote the DEV version connected to DEV db into TESt env. And after sucessfult testing you wish to promote TESTed version into PROD. My question here is how do you deal with that.

Comment: Yes, and sadly i haven't found a way that wasn't cumbersome.The way you are rewiring or sharing which IL you use, folder permissions, etc is how we accomplish it. In our cases though the dxp may be developmental, the data is usually from the prod DB though.

Comment: im not entirely sure what you want to to achieve, but have you explored automation services?

Comment: yes and they are meant for different things